# Best practices for application security with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, security, frameworks

We are setting up a new application framework and we are wondering the best practices for setting up database security for our users.  In our old framework, there was a user logon process and once the user was logged on, the framework controlled what forms and menu options a user was permitted to.  All users accessed the database with the same user account.

The disadvantage to this approach is that you cant use SYSTEM_USER to find out who is making a particular database request.

The new framework will still have a logon form and it will control what menu options a person can access.  Should we be setting up a database user account every time a new user is added to our application?  Would this cause any licensing concerns since you cant use connection pooling?

Answer (score 0):

It won't cause licensing issues, but it will generate a large number of connections which may cause performance issues.

A better solution would be to add a parameter to your stored procedures to pass in the UserID of the current user so that it can be logged.

If passing in the parameter is undesirable, you can put the current user in CONTEXT_INFO(), or if you are using SQL 2016, SESSION_CONTEXT() and log it from there.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4094/phase-out-contextinfo-in-sql-server-2016-with-sessioncontext/

Comment: Thanks Phil for your answer.  Just the advice I was looking for